# Waiting for a file to be created in Bash

Tags: bash, unix

I need to create a bash script to wait for a file to be created. The script will use sleep command inside a while loop to periodically check on a file every 10 seconds. Print out a message while waiting. Display the content of the file once the file is created. Below is what I have tried to implement and it obviously does not work. At this point, I'm not entirely sure how to proceed.

```
#!/bin/bash
let file=$1

while '( -f !  /tmp/$1)'
do
       sleep 10
       echo "still waiting"
done

echo "Content of the file $1:"
```

Comment: `'(...)'` is a STRING, which boils down to `while true`. try `while [ !-f /tmp/$1 ]` or similar.

Comment: @MarcB, eh? Not `while true` at all; it's `while false`, since that string isn't a valid command. If it were inside a test, *then* it might be ture.

Comment: BTW, in the future, consider using `bash -x yourscript` to figure out what's going on during execution -- in this case, that would have showed that we were going straight from `'( -f !  /tmp/$1)'` to `echo "Content of the file $1:"`, thus ruling out problem with the `sleep` (since it wasn't being run at all).

Comment: @MarcB, ...btw, it would be `while [ ! -f /tmp/"$1" ]` -- the space between the `!` and the `-` is mandatory, likewise the quotes around the expansion (to avoid a wide array of undesired behaviors from string-splitting and glob expansion). Or `while ! test -f "/tmp/$1"`, or any number of other ways of writing it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem here is with the test, not the sleep (as the original question hypothesized). The smallest possible fix might look as follows:

```
while ! test -f "/tmp/$1"; do
  sleep 10
  echo "Still waiting"
done
```

---

Keep in mind the syntax for a `while` loop:

> ```
> while: while COMMANDS; do COMMANDS; done
>     Expand and execute COMMANDS as long as the final command in the
>     `while' COMMANDS has an exit status of zero.
> ```

That is to say, the first argument given to `while`, expanding the loop, is a *command*; it needs to follow the same syntax rules as any other shell command.

`-f` is valid as an argument to `test` -- a command which is also accessible under the name `[`, requiring a `]` as the last argument when used in that name -- but it's not valid as a command in and of itself -- and when passed as part of a string, it's not even a shell word that *could* be parsed as an individual command name or argument.

When you run `'( -f !  /tmp/$1)'` as a command, inside quotes, the shell is looking for an actual command with exactly that name (including spaces). You probably don't have a file named `'/usr/bin/( -f !  /tmp/$1)'` in your PATH or any other command by that name found, so it'll always fail -- exiting the `while` loop immediately.

---

By the way -- if you're willing to make your code OS-specific, there are approaches other than using `sleep` to wait for a file to exist. Consider, for instance, `inotifywait`, from the `inotify-tools` package:

```
while ! test -f "/tmp/$1"; do
  echo "waiting for a change to the contents of /tmp" >&2
  inotifywait --timeout 10 --event create /tmp >/dev/null || {
    (( $? == 2 )) && continue  ## inotify exit status 2 means timeout expired
    echo "unable to sleep with inotifywait; doing unconditional 10-second loop" >&2
    sleep 10
  }
done
```

The benefit of an inotify-based interface is that it returns immediately upon a filesystem change, and doesn't incur polling overhead (which can be particularly significant if it prevents a system from sleeping).

---

By the way, some practice notes:

- Quoting expansions in filenames (ie. `"/tmp/$1"`) prevents names with spaces or wildcards from being expanded into multiple distinct arguments.
- Using `>&2` on `echo` commands meant to log for human consumption keeps stderr available for programmatic consumption
- `let` is used for **math**, not general-purpose assignments. If you want to use `"$file"`, nothing wrong with that -- but the assignment should just be `file=$1`, with no preceding `let`.

Comment: For Mac users, you could use `fswatch` instead of `inotifywait`: `fswatch --event Created --event Updated  "$INPUT_DIR"`